# javascript .js file external url

Tags: javascript, html, url, path

I am using gnuplot-js https://github.com/chhu/gnuplot-JS when I am without my laptop at university.
Is it possible to use an external url for gnuplot.js file? I host index.html, gnuplot_api.js on https://mywebsite.com/ but I would like to use another url for gnuplot.js file (for example https://external.com/blabla/ok/no/gnuplot.js) because this file is really big!

Maybe this is the part I should edit on index.html. How? :

```html
<script src='gnuplot_api.js'></script>
        <script>
                gnuplot = new Gnuplot('gnuplot.js');
                gnuplot.onOutput = function(text) {
                    document.getElementById('output').value += text + '\n';
                    document.getElementById('output').scrollTop = 99999;
                };
```

or maybe this part on gnuplot_api.js?:

```js
var Gnuplot = function(js_filename) {
        this.worker = new Worker(js_filename);
        this.output = [];
        this.error = [];
        this.isRunning = false;
```

Thank you very much for your support

Answer (score 0):

It appears Gnuplot use an onboard webworker, so the path provided to the constructor should be on the same domain than the script.

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/chhu/gnuplot-JS/www/gnuplot_api.js'></script>
<script>
    gnuplot = new Gnuplot('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/chhu/gnuplot-JS/www/gnuplot.js');
</script>
```

Comment: gnuplot_api.js is a small file. gnuplot.js is a huge file! I want to edit index.html by adding url to the function: "<script src='gnuplot_api.js'></script>
        <script>
                gnuplot = new Gnuplot('http//url.com/gnuplot.js');
                gnuplot.onOutput = function(text) {
                    document.getElementById('output').value += text + '\n';
                    document.getElementById('output').scrollTop = 99999;
                };" But it does not work

Comment: You can also use cdn for `gnuplot.js` (see the update)

Comment: On Chrome Console I get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) on http://example.com/gnuplot.js". The original index.html file is without a <script scr=""> for gnuplot.js file so I think the javascript code is searching the file on http://example.com even if I add "<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/chhu/gnuplot-JS/www/gnuplot.js"></script>". A solution should be found by changing "gnuplot = new Gnuplot('gnuplot.js');" on index.html and/or "var Gnuplot = function(js_filename) {
        this.worker = new Worker(js_filename);" on gnuplot_api.js.